# how to focus on this TD javasript

Tags: javascript

my code is error `td.textContent.focus is not a function`

my function is like this

```
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    [].forEach.call(tds, function(td) {
            
        if (td.textContent == ' Survey (Notes)') {
            td.textContent.focus();
        }
    });
```

when i use alert below condition of text.context is show a result
but when i'm using focus it's show an error

i want to focus on that result when the page is loaded

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. By default, `td` elements are not focusable. You need to add the `tabindex` attribute to make it focusable.
2. Focus on the `td` element, not `textContent`: Once the `td` element is made focusable, you can call the focus method on the element itself.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    [].forEach.call(tds, function(td) {
        if (td.textContent === ' Survey (Notes)') {
            td.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
            td.focus();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use td.focus(),even td can not be focused

```html
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    [].forEach.call(tds, function(td) {
            
        if (td.textContent == ' Survey (Notes)') {
            td.focus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i've tried that but still can't focus on that td but not showing any error

Comment: you are right, the focus can be used in some element like ' input',but not td

Comment: it's solved im using scrollIntoView thanks btw